# BeautifulSoup4 Error in GUI Application Py2EXE

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, runtime-error, py2exe

I have build a GUI application that uses BeautifulSoup4. After trial and error of finally getting it to open, the application doesn't work, and throws an info box when I close it saying to check the log. This is what the log says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in newessay
  File "essay.pyc", line 10, in __init__
  File "essay.pyc", line 36, in buildDocument
  File "bs4\element.pyc", line 935, in __getattr__
  File "bs4\element.pyc", line 1146, in find
  File "bs4\element.pyc", line 1167, in find_all
  File "bs4\element.pyc", line 495, in _find_all
  File "bs4\element.pyc", line 1185, in descendants
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'
```

Do you have any idea why this would be? BeautifulSoup4 is included in the libraries because I have the .egg unzipped. Would that be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suppose to be a html5lib bug described on [BeautifulSoap4 launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1182089):

> html5lib tree builder sometimes creates tags with no next_element